# Why won't Vista Sidebar Gadget show up in Gadget Gallery?

Tags: windows-vista, vista64, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'd like to create a sidebar gadget in Vista.  I've followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163370.aspx) on how to create one to the letter. However, the gadget simply will not show up in the Gadget Gallery when I go to Add Gadgets in the sidebar.

I've tried resetting the sidebar, deleting the settings file next to the gadgets folder, making sure my xml file is stored as UTF-8, etc.  Still nothing.

**NOTE:** To those looking to retag, this *is* programming-related.  Please follow the link to see what I'm talking about.  I'm trying to get the some verbatim tutorial code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are looking for your custom gadget in the Gadget Gallery check that the search box does not display 'Microsoft Corporation'.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6b6b3e75c7.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6b6b3e75c7.png)

This is the default and will only display Microsoft's gadgets, change this to 'All gadgets' and you should see your custom one appear:

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to zip or cab your gadget and rename the extension to .gadget  Then you can drop it in  c:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsSidebar\Gadgets.  That should make it available in the Gadget Gallery.

Comment: I've tried loading a .gadget package as well and that hasn't worked.  I'd assume it was an issue with my system if it weren't happening at home and at work.

Answer (score 2):

Did you put all your files in a subdirectory of %appdata%..\local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets? Putting the files in an archive isn’t required, it just extracts everything to that directory during installation.

If you created an archive with .gadget extension, make sure all files are in the root directory of that archive.

Comment: I have it in a C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\test.gadget    folder

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you replace ” with " if you copy the gadget.xml from the tutorial. Also make sure src="something.html" points to a valid html-page.

Comment: I've triple checked that the quotes are correct and my src is pointing to the exact named files from the example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that having a settings.htm file is mandatory since after adding one, my test worked.

Comment: why was this downvoted?  This was the actual reason things were not working for me.